# Perl script automation: search for certain items in notepad

Tags: windows, perl, automation

I have to search for certain items using `CTRL+F` which are almost 100 in number daily in notepad.I want to know that, is there any way by which I can write a script or anything else,to which I will pass all the items,and it will give me the search output if it succeeds i.e. it 
should return  all the items which are found in the notepad.

I am working on `windows`.Please help as it is causing waste of time for me and in near future if the items increase up to 1000,it would be a huge workaround for me.

I have some idea of Perl and I think it is possible in Perl, so I have raised the question here.But if you want to give your script in any other language ,please give.I n
eed a solution.

Comment: What do you want? The position of the matches? the lines of the matches? It's crazy simple to do this in Perl without notepad.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for the reply.I just want to know the all the matches i.e. Suppose out of the 100 items 19 items are there in the notepad.So.my script should return  all the 19 items saying that these are the items which are found in notepad.Please help.

Comment: What exactly should the script output?  The lines on which the matches are? The line numbers?  What do you want to do with the result?

Comment: the script output should be :All the matches items that are found in the notepad.I just want to know the matched items.

Comment: How is a matched item different from the part of the item that matches? Is an item a line, or a word?  What is a word exactly? If the same word is matched multiple times, does it need to be repeated in the output?

Answer (score 3):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $qfn   = 'file.txt';
my @terms = ( 'foo', 'bar', ... );

my %terms_not_found = map { $_ => 1 } @terms;

open(my $fh, '<', $qfn)
   or die("Can't open \"$qfn\": $!\n");

while (<$fh>) {
   for my $term (keys(%terms_not_found)) {
      delete $terms_not_found{$term} if /\Q$term/;
   }

   last if !%terms_not_found;
}

print("Found:\n");
print("$_\n")
   for grep !$terms_not_found{$_}, @terms;
```

Answer (score 2):

You basically want `grep`.

```
grep -o pattern file.txt
```

Comment: I agree, but maybe `grep -of pattern.txt file.txt | sort | uniq -c` to search for all patterns at once.

Comment: [GNU grep is also available for Windows as a stand-alone binary.](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm) Cygwin has the disadvantage that you install half another operating system on top of your operating system when all you want is one command.

Answer (score 2):

Note that I don't want this to turn into a suggestion thread, but sometimes the simplest solution is one you don't have to write yourself.

http://www.wingrep.com/

From the features page:

- **Command line interface:** A powerful UNIX-like command line interface allows Windows Grep to be driven from a DOS box or other Windows shell.

You could use the command-line options of wingrep in a batch script to perform your search, and set it up in windows as a daily/weekly/whatever scheduled task to perform your automation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how perl script could go.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(FILE,'<file.txt');
my @items=qw(abc 123 abc123 xyz);
my @match;

while(<FILE>)
{
 my @words=split(/ /,$_);
 foreach my $el(@items) {
    @match=grep {$el eq $_} @words;
    local $\=" ";    # Output separator
    print @match;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4600/Notepad-RE-Regular-Expressions
It is a very nice tool. You can use perl compatible regular expressions from "boost::regex".

In order to do a grep, you need to use following replace syntax on that tool "^(?:(?!TEXT).)*\r\n"
That is the pattern to be searched, and replace with box should be empty.

That regexp will remove any lines without the TEXT in it.